Sharepoint Online List - EditForm - Force a value in a field when we open it
I searched on this forum and on internet but didn't find my answer.
I use a Sharepoint online List and have an approval flow on each change done on items.
The approval flow is waiting a value = 'New' in the column 'ApprovalStatus'. This approach is to remove the infinite loop in power automate. Choices ('New','Under reviewing','Approved','Rejected')
When the approval is done 'ApprovalStatus' is changed to approved or Rejected.
If someone else wants to change again this item by using the EditForm, I would like to force the field ApprovalStatus to 'New' independently of is previous value.
Of course, no change when we are just reading the item
Do you know how to change a value in a field when we open the EditForm?
The goal will be to hide this field to be sure the process manage it and not the user


You can try and develop an SPFX Form Extension.
Here is the Microsoft article to get you started -->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer
You would need to hook into the render() function, get the HTML element where the Approval value is stored, and change it in the DOM.
There is no out of the box solution, for what you try to achieve.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, i'm not sharepoint admin so I don't think I will be able to develop this form
